# Generate Documentation of NAnt scripts

Tags: deployment, build, nant

I'm writing documentation on the build and deployment scripts that we use. I'm hoping there is a tool similar to Sandcastle or ndoc but for NAnt scripts. I've searched for this but results I get back show me how to use NAnt to document C# or VB code.

I would probably have written much of the docs by now, but if we had a tool that could regenerate the docs, then that would take some of the pain out of keeping our documentation up to date!

Any ideas???

Comment: can you provide a small example of a nant-script to be documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there exists no special nant documentation tool. You can use an XSL stylesheet to map the targets of build scripts to HTML and use the `comment(node)` function as documentation.

Comment: Thanks, Marking as answer. Will give it a shot. Sorry for late response didn't get a notification of this.